# When should I use ConstantDataArray versus ConstantArray?

Tags: llvm, llvm-3.0, llvm-c++-api

I'm using the LLVM 3.3 C++-API.  My code creates arrays using `ConstantArray::get`, and multidimensional arrays with recursive code (the innermost rank is first converted to a vector of Constant*s, as above, then that is used to initialize the next-innermost rank, and so on).

I tried to optimize this by saying that if an array's element type satisfies the `ConstantDataArray::isElementTypeCompatible` predicate, then it should be initialized using `ConstantDataArray::get`.

Here's a more concrete example to show what I mean:

1. Say the array I want to create would be declared like this in C++:

   int x[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
2. The innermost rank (type int[3]) is a simple array type, so two CDAs are created.
3. The next rank is an array of two int[3]s.  It is not a simple type, so a regular `ConstantArray` is created.  The argument is an `ArrayRef<Constant*>` containing the two CDAs.

At step 3, `ConstantArray` complains because the initializer does not have exactly the right type.  Here's the message:

```
.../llvm-3.3.src/lib/IR/Constants.cpp:754:
static llvm::Constant* llvm::ConstantArray::get(llvm::ArrayType*,
llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Constant*>):

Assertion `V[i]->getType() == Ty->getElementType()
&& "Wrong type in array element initializer"' failed.
```

I though `ConstantDataArray` was a substitute for `ConstantArray` when the element type is simple enough, but maybe I have it wrong.  What's the correct way to understand it?

### Update

This looks like a bug in my code (outside of LLVM).  `ConstantDataArray` does appear to be a transparent substitute for `ConstantArray`.

Here's the code I put together to demonstrate the problem.  It actually runs through without any complaints from LLVM:

```
// int[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
IntegerType* i64 = IntegerType::get(mod->getContext(), 64);
Constant* one = ConstantInt::get(i64, 1);
Constant* two = ConstantInt::get(i64, 2);
Constant* three = ConstantInt::get(i64, 3);
Constant* four = ConstantInt::get(i64, 4);
Constant* five = ConstantInt::get(i64, 5);
Constant* six = ConstantInt::get(i64, 6);

ArrayType* int_3 = ArrayType::get(i64, 3);
ArrayType* int_2_3 = ArrayType::get(int_3, 2);
// Constant* array123 = ConstantArray::get(int_3, std::vector<Constant*>{one,two,three});
Constant* array123 = ConstantDataArray::get(mod->getContext(), std::vector<uint64_t>{1,2,3});
// Constant* array456 = ConstantArray::get(int_3, std::vector<Constant*>{four,five,six});
Constant* array456 = ConstantDataArray::get(mod->getContext(), std::vector<uint64_t>{4,5,6});
Constant* array = ConstantArray::get(int_2_3, std::vector<Constant*>{array123, array456});
```

In case anyone is interested, the assertion stems from my reversing the array extents.  `int[2][3]` is an array of two arrays of three.  I'm overloading `operator[]` to build an array type as `i64[2][3]`, where `i64` is an object that holds an `IntegerType*` and overloads `operator[]`.  The problem is that this builds an array of three arrays of two.

Comment: Your 3 steps look fine, seems to me the fault is likely in the `ArrayType` you provide to that `get` method. Could you show the code snippet in which you actually call `get`, including the creation of the first argument?

Comment: @Oak Thanks.  Putting together the example led me to the problem, as it does 99% of the time.

Comment: Great to hear. It's best if you post an actual answer to your question, though, instead of editing it.